# Submitting inputs of different types in a single form using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is what I am trying to do...
I am creating a single form for both uploading zip files and entering data like names, numbers, etc...
Can I do it using codeigniter?
If anyone can suggest a possible solution it would be very helpful....
Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's doable but it's a pain in the ass. You need to basically fake an ajax file upload using an iFrame. Honestly make it a two step form, it's a lot easier. Have them fill out their data, when that passes move them to the upload page or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CodeIgniter's [File Upload Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html). You can follow the tutorial there to setup a uploading form as well as other inputs. Notice that to upload something, you have to use `form_open_multipart` instead of `form_open`.

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question though. He wants the upload and the data on the same page.

Comment: @RickCalder Are you saying we cannot have both input fields and upload field in the same form? I didn't know that.

Comment: You can, it's just a pain to process I find.